# How to go from Manado to Davao on a budget?

Tags: air-travel, budget, indonesia, sea-travel, philippines

I want to go from [Manado (Sulawesi, Indonesia](https://goo.gl/maps/Eebqr)) to [Davao (Philippines)](https://goo.gl/maps/pgxep).

The problem is that the only solution I found was to fly for 400 USD. This price is out of my budget so I started looking for alternative solutions (flight agencies, ferries) but could not find anything that worked.

I found that [Lion Air](http://lionair.co.id/) flies from Manado to [Tahuna (Indonesia)](https://goo.gl/maps/D27IV) for 40 USD, which is pretty good considering that Tahuna is half way to Davao. But I could not find a solution for the Tahuna-Davao part.

[image: Lion Air flight for Manado to Tahuna]

Note: the above screenshot indicates "Wings Air" because [`(Wings Air) was established as a wholly owned subsidiary of Lion Air`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wings_Air)

Comment: Did you check rome2rio for useful suggestions?

Comment: Manado-Davao is not looking good http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Manado/Davao?dates=2015-8-11 and the same goes for Tahuna-Davao http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Kecamatan-Tahuna/Davao

Comment: What's your budget ?

Comment: 1'500'000 IDR would be ideal.

Answer (score 3):

Unless things have changed since I last looked at this (and it's been a few years), **your only option is to fly**.  In these days of low cost carriers, it may also be cheaper to fly via eg. Kuala Lumpur on Air Asia, even though this makes no sense geographically.

And for why there are no ferries: the southern Philippines (Mindanao) are strongly Muslim and in parts little short of a war zone, while northern Sulawesi is strongly Christian. There's thus less cultural connection, and consequently less demand, than you'd think from the distance alone.

Comment: Interesting indeed. So, I did search this journey on several flight search engine, cheapest deal I found was 400USD :(

Comment: Are you dead set on Davao?  Cebu is easier/cheaper to get to and by most accounts more pleasant.